# Threading in Python 3 for image processing using global variables doesnt seem to be more efficient

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I am detecting and tracking QR tags from a live webcam recording. I decided to use threading to make a seperate thread to read/assign the frame continuously to global variable image and have the main thread loop continuously through the image processing loop, taking each frame (image) as needed to identify the tags. I implemented this with threading (prev. explanation) and without threading (recording initiates outside of loop and csv.read() calls the current frame in the image processing loop).  Both versions output the live recording and highlight edges of the QR code.

I expected the threading version to be more efficient but it seems that the threading is not that much more efficient (probably even worse).The threading version is more "flickery". Why would this be? Is my implementation incorrect?

[QR tracker without threading](https://github.com/Solarpa/Object_tracking/blob/master/QR_vdetect.py)

[QR tracker with threading](https://github.com/Solarpa/Object_tracking/blob/master/QRv_thread.py)

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I implemented the same functionality in the threaded version without using a global variable. Instead, I used a class with method frame which uses cv2.read(). It looks like I may be getting better results, but probably right on par with what I get without threading.

Comment: AFAIK opencv doesn't release the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: AFAIK OpenCV does release the GIL. I am no expert in Python, but it looks to me as though your `find_frame()` writes without any sync into `image`, probably while `decode()` is still processing the previous frame.

Comment: I think you need to accurately benchmark the acquisition without any processing and the processing without any acquisition. If the processing is significantly slower, you may need to generate a queue of frames in acquisition and have 2 or more processing threads popping frames off the queue.